# Computer Vision - is splitting by annotation considered data leakage?

Tags: computer-vision, data-leakage

We are using a COCO like dataset, with around 1500 images and 4700 annotations.

We want to define our train-test dataset split.

Will splitting our dataset by annotations cause data leakage? We fear that it might because both the train and test will potentially have the same image, but different annotations.